# fatal error: 'include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/allocation.h' file not found

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am working with a tensorflow lite library and trying to import it in Android Studio
Although I face issue in Native-lib.cpp and all the header files.
this is my interpreter.h file headers
Although allocation.h is available in include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/allocation.h
Still it shows file not found

So do I need to change the location of the cmakeList.txt or what should I do to avoid this error
Here is the github repo - https://github.com/usefulsensors/openai-whisper/tree/main/android_app/Whisper-TFLIte-Android-Example

Interpreter.h file headers

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <atomic>
#include <complex>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/allocation.h" //HERE IS THE ERROR
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/c/common.h"  // IWYU pragma: export
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/core/api/error_reporter.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/core/subgraph.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/experimental/remat/metadata_util.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/experimental/resource/initialization_status.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/experimental/resource/resource_base.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/external_cpu_backend_context.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/internal/signature_def.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/interpreter_options.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/portable_type_to_tflitetype.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/profiling/root_profiler.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/signature_runner.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/stderr_reporter.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/string_type.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/type_to_tflitetype.h"
```

Then here is my Native-lib.cpp file headers

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/core/interpreter.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"
#include "whisper.h"
#include "input_features.h"
#include "include/tf-lite-api/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/delegate.h"
```

Here is what i have defined as path to cmakelist.txt in build.gradle

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
```

Here is the project structure[[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tBL6.png)][[File available at the location but studio doesnt recognize it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCUzW.png)]

I tried changing the path of native lib and cmake but to no avail

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compile the parts of TFLite needed to run your code together with your project. Your question is a bit unclear though.

But I would not recommend doing that, instead compile TFLite to a static or a dynamic library. Here's some instructions on how to do that:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake

After including this library in your `CmakeLists.txt` you just need these headers to run your inference:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/tools/gen_op_registration.h"
```

I would also recommend putting Tensorflow as a subfolder to your repo. This will greatly simplify your compilation process.